# Customer Registration error

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, login

yestarday I discovered this problem in Magento, if I try to signup from the frontend with a new account, after filling all fields and push the signup button the page load and it show up a blank page with this:

```
string: {my_password} (in my_password is shown the password I have used to signup)
```

So I thought was something related to the frontend, I decided to signup the account manually from the Backend, the result is that when I save the account, the backend load a blank page with the word:

```
NULL
```

So I open up the console in firefox, nothing, at this point I enabled the system logs, and do again the procedure, and this is what the log tell when I try to manually signup the account from the backend (even if I try to edit an existing account).

```
ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /magentostore/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3937
```

I really don't understand what to do, and what is causing the issue, I have opened that file Mysql.php, but at the line 3937 there is a public function to check if all transactions have been committed, nothing more.

I'm running Magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Somebody added output for debugging with `var_dump()`. Search the Magento code base in `app` for "var_dump", I think the core doesn't use this function so you should easily find the culprit.